# How can I group by same field with multiple values?

Tags: elasticsearch

When I search for elasticsearch aggregation, I only find `multi_terms` which is used to group by multiple fields. But I am looking for how to group by one field with multiple values.

I have a field `product` which value can be `fruit`, `electronic`, `veg`, `furniture` etc. I like to group by all document whose value is either `fruit` or `veg`. How can I achieve that?

I am looking for a way without updating index mapping. Since the value of `product` is changed frequently, I need to support any combination of group field at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use script along with terms aggregation.

I have used [runtime_mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime-search-request.html) which is a script , it will emit single value for product vegetable  and fruit, which you can use to group data.

You can also index [runtime fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime-mapping-fields.html) to improve performance.

```
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "product_custom": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": {
        "source": """
                      if(doc["product.keyword"].value=="vegetable" 
                        || doc["product.keyword"].value=="fruit")
                      {
                        emit("vegetable/fruit");  
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        emit(doc["product.keyword"].value);
                      }
                  """
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "product_custom": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product_custom"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "product_custom" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "vegetable/fruit",
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key" : "electronic",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

**Update**

Runtime fields are available from version 7.11 onwards

You can also use scripts in terms aggregation to achieve same

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "product_custom": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
                     if(doc["product.keyword"].value=="vegetable" 
                        || doc["product.keyword"].value=="fruit")
                      {
                        return "vegetable/fruit";  
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        return doc["product.keyword"].value;
                      }
                    """
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

scripts and run/time mapping are slow as everything is being done at search time.
You can add runtime field to your index with out need of recreating index. it will give better performance than script

Comment: this approach requires rebuilding index for any change on combination of group fields? Is there a way to achieve it without building index, like runtime aggregate?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao above does not require any change to index. It is all in query

Comment: is it a new feature? I am using 7.10 and it seems it doesn't have this feature